# Sessions not destroying

Tags: php, session

My 'log in' code

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trade2_users WHERE email = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."' AND pass = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])."'");
if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
header("Location: index.php");
}
```

My 'log out' code

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("Location: log_in.php");
```

For whatever reason my log out code isn't working (isn't really destroying the session). $_SESSION['name'] is still set after the log out script runs.

Comment: How can you say your `SESSION` is not destroyed? Are you echoing it on `login page`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using :

```
session_unset();
header("Location: log_in.php");
```

Comment: of even more specific: unset($_SESSION['name']);

Comment: Note that `session_unset()` is a legacy method. The doco states *"Only use session_unset() for older deprecated code that does not use $_SESSION."*

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/function.session-destroy.php)

> In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.

[Example #1](http://www.php.net/manual/function.session-destroy.php#example-4714) on that same page shows you exactly what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I typically over-write the values instead of trying to remove the session.

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
    unset($_SESSION[$key]);
}
```